# JSON says Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'

Tags: json

I was trying to format my json in jsonformatter.org and I'm not sure why I'm getting the below error

```
Parse error on line 1:

...","topBrand":false}{"_id":{"$oid":"601c

----------------------^

Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'

[error][1]
```

Sample JSON:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"601ac115be37ce2ead437551"},"barcode":"511111019862","category":"Baking","categoryCode":"BAKING","cpg":{"$id":{"$oid":"601ac114be37ce2ead437550"},"$ref":"Cogs"},"name":"test brand @1612366101024","topBrand":false}
{"_id":{"$oid":"601c5460be37ce2ead43755f"},"barcode":"511111519928","brandCode":"BUCKS","category":"Beverages","categoryCode":"BEVERAGES","cpg":{"$id":{"$oid":"5332f5fbe4b03c9a25efd0ba"},"$ref":"Cogs"},"name":"Starbucks","topBrand":false}
```

Comment: The sample contains two separate json documents, so it realises that and it's failing at the start of the second one.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your input is not JSON but [JSON lines](https://jsonlines.org) (not a standard format, just a bunch of JSONs, one per line). Split it then handle each line as a separate JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you posted contains two separate JSON documents, and is thus invalid. That's what the error is complaining about, it expected `EOF` (i.e. End of File), but it instead got the opening-brace from the second JSON document.

Either format them one at a time, or merge them into one document somehow.

For example, you could turn it into a list:

```
{
    "data": [
        { ... },
        { ... }
    ]

}
```

Or a larger compound object:

```
{
    "data1": { ... },
    "data2": { ... }
}
```

Comment: Is the below correct for formatting it into a larger compound object?                                                                                  
{
    data1: {"_id":{"$oid":"5ff1e194b6a9d73a3a9f1052"},"active":true,"createdDate":{"$date":1609687444800},"lastLogin":{"$date":1609687537858},"role":"consumer","signUpSource":"Email","state":"WI"},
    data2: {"_id":{"$oid":"5ff1e194b6a9d73a3a9f1052"},"active":true,"createdDate":{"$date":1609687444800},"lastLogin":{"$date":1609687537858},"role":"consumer","signUpSource":"Email","state":"WI"}
}

Comment: I would use https://jsonformatter.org/ rather than ask me, because if you ask me I'm just going to go to that website myself, as it'll catch issues more reliably than I can. Not to mention it'll respond faster than me.


That said, your JSON is still incorrect because you forgot the quotes around `data1` and `data2`. If you add the quotes your JSON is fine.